# How to add part of time in Android

Tags: android, date, time

I have a code returning me a string (HH:mm).

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        java.util.Date dateObj;
        try {
            dateObj = curFormater.parse(start);

            SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); 
            String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj); 
            startView.setText(newDateStr);
            Emission_start = newDateStr;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(" * Error", e.toString());
        }
```

It works great... But right now I would like to:

1. add x (is dynamically provided) minutes (x = from 5 to 1000 minutes) and transform to time (example time:3:45, add 25 minutes, transform to time 4:10)
2. Get current time and calculate difference between current time and time from step 1 (4:10)
3. Get time difference (from step 2) in minutes!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested, but something like this should work:

1. `long newDate = dateObj.getTime() +
   (x * 60 * 1000)`
2. `long diff =
   System.currentTimeMillis() - newDate`
3. `double diffInMins = diff / (60.0 * 1000.0)`

Comment: Smth like this I've alerady tried.. (Have tried this one as well) and the result is wrong... But I have no idea why...

Comment: After some test I found out that point 3. or 2. is not correct... newDate is OK ...

Comment: Wups ... that is due to Emulator error ... Posting wrong current time.. fixed that! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

1. use Calendar

   Calendar calInstance = new GregorianCalendar();
   calInstance.setTime(dateObj);

Then add any fragment you want, for minutes do

```
calInstance.add(Calendar.MINUTE, XX)
```

To, transform use your formatter

```
postFormatter.format(calInstance.getTime());
```

1. is trivial
2. Diff in minutes can be calculated easily as well

   long diffInMins = (currTimeInMillis - calInstance.getTimeInMillis())/(1000 * 60);